# Restrict SSH access for one user of accessing machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, debian

I have two virtual machines VM1(Ubuntu) & VM2(Debian). VM1 has a single user "admin" & VM2 has two users "test1" & "test2". What I want is that only test1 was able to access VM1 through ssh  whereas test2 user should not able to access VM1 through ssh.

i.e if I logged in as test1 user & type ssh admin@VM1host.com than remote machine should allow this user to access the machine(VM1) whereas if I'm logged in as test2 & try the same command than the remote machine(VM1) should restrict ssh access for this user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict ssh access to ssh keys only (disable password login with `PasswordAuthentication no`) and only allow the key from test1 user account in `~admin/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the VM1 machine.

Obs: the public key you will need to allow in admin@VM1 will be the public key `/home/test1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on VM2 machine (or something similar if you use rsa keys).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the AllowUsers (or AllowGroups) properties in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
AllowUsers test1
```

[man of sshd_config](http://www.openssh.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config)

Comment: AllowUsers only works for the users present on VM1 machine i.e only allow ssh-login as admin user.However through AllowUsers host can be checked i.e admin@host.So it will check the host to be allowed.But in my case Both the users are on same machine i.e VM2 ,so same host.

Comment: Now I understand. Maybe that is not possibile with ssh client. Try to read deeply the man of ssh_config file: http://www.openssh.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config

Comment: It is possible to do so requiring ssh keys to login (disable password login and only allow keys for ssh).